# Cant load AssetImage from Flutter package

Tags: flutter

I have created a package called app_images that should only be downloaded from the appstore once needed.

I have added a few handler methods so I can get the images from that package via a method.
all images in the package are located in "assets/"

When I want to access an image from that package in my flutter app, it says that the AssetImage("assets/myImage") cannot be loaded.

If I put the images into my flutter app's "assets/" folder and add it to the pubspec.yaml instead, it suddenly works, although I am still relying on the package. This feels like something in the framework is not right or that I am not managing my images in the right way within that package.

What can I do to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: please consider adding your code